# Set header html element level dynamically depending on partial view nesting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, nested

i have created a partial view layout using bootstrap to display a single panel. whenever I call a partial view I use this layout and pass the section name on the ViewBag.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        @ViewBag.SectionName            
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the issue is that inside a partial view, I may be calling another partial view using the same layout multiple times. This would result in nested panels with multiple levels.

The issue is, that I want to add a header element to the panel heading element containing the section name depending on the partial view nesting level. If we had three levels, the code would look like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default main-content-panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-default main-content-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2>Section 2</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="container">
                   <div class="panel panel-default main-content-panel">
                       <div class="panel-heading">
                           <h3>Section 3</h3>
                       </div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="container">
                              Some content and respective closing divs....
```

how could I accomplish this? An idea or solution that does not uses JS will be appreciated.

Comment: Since Bootstrap Panels requires javascript, why do you not want a javascript solution?

Comment: I am working on an accessible website and one requirement is for the web site to mantain its logical distribution JavaScript is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

JS would certainly be the *easiest* way, but since you've explicitly disallowed that, the only option is to evaluate how many nesting levels there will be *before* they're actually rendered.

There's not a whole lot of detail here about what data structure represents these sections, but generally, you'll need to do a recursive count of the lower levels while rendering the upper level, and change the heading accordingly in the partial responsible for it. I can't give any more guidance than that without more code.

Long and short, you only get one bite at the apple when a partial is being rendered. You can't wait until the end and then modify something that happened in a previously rendered partial.